# return multi variables php after processing by AJAX

Tags: php, ajax

I need to answer PHP processing with Ajax return
But I do not know how to turn two variables

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
 <title>Sceener Ajax</title> 
 <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


 <div id="name"></div>
 <div id="family"></div>



<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            success: function( result_1 ) {
                var name = result_1;
                $("#name").html(name);
            }
        });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ajax.php

```
<?php
$name = 'My Name';
$family = 'My Family';
echo ( $name );
?>
```

How can I do this please help me

Comment: I tried but did not succeed json

Comment: `json_encode( array( 'name' => $name, 'family' => $family) )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return a json object instead of a string.

In PHP, create an array with the values and create a json string from it:

```
$response = [
    'name' => 'My Name',
    'family' => 'My Family'
];

// Encode the array as a json string
echo json_encode($response);
```

Add `dataType: 'json'` to the ajax call, to get jQuery to parse the response as a json object and then fetch the values from it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax ({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.php",
        dataType: 'json', // <-- This will make jQuery handle the json response correctly
        success: function( response ) {
            // Now you can get both values from the json object
            console.log(response.name);
            console.log(response.family);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Put all the values you want to return in an array, encode it to JSON, and read it back in your javascript:

So the PHP becomes

```
<?php
    $name = 'My Name';
    $family = 'My Family';
    $result = array ('name' => $name, 'family' => $family);
    echo ( json_encode($name ));
?>
```

And your javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            success: function( result ) {
                var name = result.name;
                var family = result.family;
                $("#name").html(name);
            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your PHP create an array or an object to contain all your data

```
<?php
$reply['name'] = 'My Name';
$reply['family' = 'My Family';
// this will convert the array to a JSON String 
// for transmission to the browser
echo json_encode($reply);
?>
```

In your javascript code to expect an object to be returned

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            dataType = 'json',      // tell jquery to expect a JSON String
                                    //and auto convert to a js object
            success: function( data ) {
                $("#name").val(data.name);
                $("#family").val(data.family);

            }
        });
});
</script>
```

Comment: not work ! 

console error is : 
Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

Comment: Do you have something on your page with an `id="family"`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php $data['name']= 'My Name'; 
$data['family'] = 'My Family'; 
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

You got answer in json format.